# Is it possible to call a user-defined function written in a worksheet from a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, worksheet, vba

I know that users can define their own functions in `Modules`, and then call it in a Excel formula. For instance, if the following function is written in a `Module`, `=f()` in a cell will return `10`.

```
Function f()
   f = 10
End Function
```

I would like to know what will happen if a function is written in a `Sheet` (`Microsoft Excel Objects`). My test shows that calling it from a cell formula doesn't work.

Could anyone tell me if I am correct?

Going further, is it correct to say that in a cell formula `=Sheet1!fun()` is always impossible, because a function defined in `Sheet1` can't be called like this (but it can well be called by a sub defined in `Sheet1`).

Comment: @bonCodigo It's hardly a duplicate given that the OP says "I know that <contents of the linked accepted answer>".

Comment: @GSerg Looks like it. Infact OP's main question points at "is it correct to say that in a cell formula =Sheet1!fun() is always impossible"

Comment: My main question is indeed "is it correct to say that in a cell formula =Sheet1!fun() is always impossible"... I just checked the question already answered, its answer didn't directly clarify my doubt...

Comment: @SoftTimur  How would you propose to write a function on a regular Excel Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct to say that in a cell formula =Sheet1!fun() is always
>   impossible

Yes.

> I would like to know what will happen if a function is written in a Sheet

If you have an old version of Excel (e.g 97), you could add a Macro sheet and write XL4 macros using that syntax.